# netbeans sync server -> local automaticially

Tags: netbeans, webserver, synchronization

I have been writing and managing web site scripts on a remote server through Netbeans version 7.1.  I use 2 different client computers to do this (one Windows 7 and one Ubuntu).  The problem I am having is when switching from one client machine to the other, the file systems are not the same on the clients.

For example say we have client #1 and client #2.

Client #1 files sync to server:

```
file#1
file#2
file#3
```

I go to client #2 and download all the files from the server:

Client #2 and server:

```
file#1
file#2
file#3
```

Now I delete file#2 from the client 2 which automatically syncs to the server.

Client #2 and server:

```
file#1
file#3
```

When I go back to client #1, and download the updated files from the server, I download file#1 and file#3, because these are the only files left on the server.  I never deleted file#2 from client#1, so client#1 still looks like this:

client#1

```
file#1
file#2
file#3
```

**This is the problem** because now the file systems on client#1 and the server are different.

Obviously with only one file, this is not a big deal.  But with hundreds of files, and maybe months working on client#2 before returning to client#1, it can get monotonous to manually compare every file from the client with the one on the server.

Is there a way I can sync the server files to local, where it would remove all the files from the client that do no exist on the server?

thanks

Comment: Wouldn't this question be a better fit for http://serverfault.com/?

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe.  Is there a way I can move it, or should I just re-write the question on server fault?  Thanks!

Comment: No clue :) Flag it and have a moderator move it maybe? I don't know what the proper procedure is